# AWS Athena BIGINT with ddmmyyyyhhmmss to date time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

i have a bigint data type value 10062019192751 it is said to me that it is a datetime formated as ddmmyyyyhhmmss (10-06-2019 19:27:51)

how can i convert or parse it to datetime in AWS Athena

using syntax from_unixtime, is giving me different value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Athena is based on Presto, so you can use [Date and Time Functions and Operators — Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html).

The `date_parse()` command can convert a string into a date by defining the format of the string (consult the above link to see the syntax).

Here is a solution, which first converts the number into a string (varchar) and then converts it into a date:

```
select date_parse(cast(10062019192751 as varchar),'%d%c%Y%k%i%s')
```

The output is:

```
2019-06-10 19:27:51.000
```